# Set up auto install of Ubuntu Server 18.04, also possibly 16.04

Tags: server, system-installation, maas, preseed, pxe

I am a relative newbie to the Linux, but have used Ubuntu desktop for a while. This is my first post to the community.

I am dealing with the Server now, specifically 16.04 LTS (Xenial) and 18.04 LTS (Bionic). Yes I know, 16.04 is now out of support, but we have customers who still use our app on their 16.04 systems, and may do so for a while yet.

My specific question is setting up auto install/re-install of 18.04, and 16.04. We have a couple of servers used for testing of our application, one  that runs 16.04 lTS, the other 18.04 LTS. The issue is we often need to wipe clean the server and re-install from scratch. This means fresh Ubuntu server install, then whatever application package is required. The servers each are first installed with a KVM host and gui package, then two VMs are created and deployed, each with a different set of application packages. It is often easier to just wipe clean and re-install.

I would like to set up auto install in this instance, and i have started to read up on autoinstaller, in 18.04, but I am still confused on what needs toHi, I am a realative newbie to the Linux, but have used Ubuntu desktop for a while. I am dealing with the Server now, specifically 16.04 LTS (Xenial) and 18.04 LTS (Bionic). Yes I know, 16.04 is now out of support, but we have customers who still use our app on their 16.04 systems, and may do so for a while yet.

My specific question is setting up auto install/re-install of 18.04, and 16.04. We have a couple of servers used for testing of our application, one that runs 16.04 lTS, the other 18.04 LTS. The issue is we often need to wipe clean the server and re-install from scratch. This means fresh Ubuntu server install, then whatever application package is required. The servers each are first installed with a KVM host and gui package, then two VMs are created and deployed, each with a different set of application packages. It is often easier to just wipe clean and re-install.

I would like to set up auto install in this instance, and i have started to read up on autoinstaller

be done, and also if a similar process can be done for 16.04.

So I started to read about the autoinstall config file, there is mention of kickstart etc. But once I the have configured my config file how do I proceed after this to get autoinstall to work? Do I need to specify the config file location on the boot command line in the installer (F6 key press)? Should I used netboot/PXE?

What about for 16.04? The autoinsall feature was not available for 16.04, but a preseed file option is.

Lastly, I also started reading up on MaaS, whether this would be a better option.

Sorry, a few questions, and this is my first post to this community.

Many thanks

Comment: If the Server NICs support PXE booting, and you have control of the DHCP server, PXE is the way to go. Wikipedia is your friend, aldo see `https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Boot.html`.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses. Apologies this is late, I was ill after submitting the question, so was not working. For 18.04 I am looking at PXE, short term, long term maybe setting up a MaaS environment. The company has agreed to stop support our applications on 16.04 by the end of the year, so for me Xenial is not a priority anymore. These are test configuration servers, focus will now be on 18.04 moving forward, starting to introduce support for our app on Focus (20.04).